# фейковый счётчик процентов загрузки на C для прикола "взломать пентагон?". как сделать?

Tags: c

хочу сделать прикол по типу "взломать пентагон?", чтобы при выборе "да" начинался счётчик процентов от 0% до 100%. кто знает как сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где то так. Только запускайте аккуратно, если за Вами приедут - сами отдувайтесь

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);// эта команда запускает взлом
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      printf("\r%3d%%", i);
      usleep(100000); // собственно делает 100 тысяч попыток все сломать
  }
  printf("\rЗа Вами уже выехали, никуда не уходите пожалуйста!\n");
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ :). а т только начинаю программировать, а перед друзьями выпендриться надо

Comment: не нужно, мало чего. Читайте книг побольше. А "выпендриваться" лучше другим.